# How to use efficiently Json Web Token in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jwt, authorization

I have a node js app. I'm trying to do authorization usin JWT. When my code is as i wrote below, im trying to login with a user in my database but it firstly reach the middleware and it says 'Auth Failed'. But if I delete middleware and login with a user who is in my database it returns a token to me. Then i add the middleware again and i use that token for another user, this time it works and it accepts that token for another user too! But I dont want this. I want that when I login with a user in my database, it should return a unique token for the user and then i should reach the middleware. Here is my codes:

Here is my middleware:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
try {

const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'secret_key');
req.userData = decodedToken;
next();
}catch(error) {
return res.status(401).send({
    message: 'Auth failed'
});
}
```

And here is my login code (im creating the token here) if password is true:

```
 const token = jwt.sign({
            email:user.email,
            password: user.password

        }, 
        'secret_key',
        {
            expiresIn :"2h"
        }
        )
        return res.status(200).send({ message: 'success', token: token});
```

And in app.js:

```
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/checkauth');
router.get('/api/company',checkAuth,companyController.list);
```

How can I do this authorization security using JWT as I want? Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Normally, if you have a token of user, you can get all API of authorization of that user. Because jwt of user identifies who that user is. Jwt contains a unique key to identify. In your case that is email.

Comment: I'm trying it with postman. For example when i login with a user, postman returns me a token for the user. Then I take that token and use for another user. It returns success again. But this should not happen

Comment: if strangers has a token, he can still access every api with that token

Comment: That's authorization issues, if you want specific user do different things, you can set a role for that user in jwt or your db, and every requests in your middleware you check that role to do specific thing you want

Comment: No I just want every user has a unique token. But I can use the same tokens for other users too, this should not happen

Comment: What is the meaning of "use the same tokens for other users" ?, if you have user's token, you can access to any API that you want (do not required email, password or anything else)

Comment: For example, I delete the middleware here like this : 
     router.get('/api/company',checkAuth,companyController.list);   
     router.get('/api/company',companyController.list); 
Then I login with a user that in my database with my above code. It creates a token for the user. Then I put the middleware again and take that token, add postman 'headers' and try login with another user email and password. Postman returns success because it has a token. But that token was created the previous user..

Comment: In your middleware you check userData in decodedToken compare that email with email in your db, if not exist you return auth failed. Because your token is just a encode data and decode data with secret key.

Comment: Could you open how can I check it please ?

Comment: Show your code connect to db and check login user

Comment: when you get your `jwt` you will be using it for further all the request for authorization so it will be like your password, you share it you are doomed.you just cannot prevent someone else to not to use your password. However you can prevent to give only user's data of whom `jwt` is getting used by keeping an another header `X-Authenticated-User` and in your middleware you can verify if `jwt's sub` is same as the `header's` value.